# XRDP errors when trying to use sesman-x11rdp

Tags: linux, xorg

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop on an old laptop of mine and I wanted to set it up so I could remote into it from my windows desktop. I've installed XRDP, but when I attempt to login using sesman-x11rdp it logs in, then the window shuts down.

I've checked over the logs and here is what I get at the time of login:

```
[20120123-16:49:23] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 8 started successfully
[20120123-16:49:23] [INFO ] granted TS access to user nicholas
[20120123-16:49:24] [INFO ] starting X11rdp session...
[20120123-16:49:24] [CORE ] error starting X server - user nicholas - pid 3869
[20120123-16:49:24] [DEBUG] errno: 2, description: No such file or directory
[20120123-16:49:24] [DEBUG] execve parameter list: 11
[20120123-16:49:24] [DEBUG]         argv[0] = X11rdp
[20120123-16:49:24] [DEBUG]         argv[1] = :11
[20120123-16:49:24] [DEBUG]         argv[2] = -geometry
[20120123-16:49:24] [DEBUG]         argv[3] = 1280x720
[20120123-16:49:24] [DEBUG]         argv[4] = -depth
[20120123-16:49:24] [DEBUG]         argv[5] = 16
[20120123-16:49:24] [DEBUG]         argv[6] = -bs
[20120123-16:49:24] [DEBUG]         argv[7] = -ac
[20120123-16:49:24] [DEBUG]         argv[8] = -nolisten
[20120123-16:49:24] [DEBUG]         argv[9] = tcp
[20120123-16:49:25] [DEBUG]         argv[10] = (null)
[20120123-16:49:34] [ERROR] X server for display 11 startup timeout
[20120123-16:49:34] [ERROR] X server for display 11 startup timeout
[20120123-16:49:34] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=3869 - wmpid=3868
[20120123-16:49:34] [ERROR] another Xserver is already active on display 11
[20120123-16:49:34] [DEBUG] aborting connection...
[20120123-16:49:34] [INFO ] session 3867 - user nicholas - terminated
```

Can anyone point me to the proper way to get this working with x11rdp?

Answer (score 3):

Options /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini:

```
[globals]
bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
port=3389
crypt_level=low
channel_code=1
max_bpp=16
#black=000000
grey=d6d3ce
#dark_grey=808080
#blue=08246b
#dark_blue=08246b
#white=ffffff
#red=ff0000
#green=00ff00
#background=626c72

[xrdp1]
name=RDP
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
xserverbpp=16

[xrdp2]
name=VNC
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
```

May be it will help you.
Line 7, bpp(bit per pixel) must be 16, and sections with module libxup.so too.
Clients must connect to XRDP server with options 16 bit per pixel.

Sorry my english is bad.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and this solution does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

xrdp and X11rdp server are not the same. xrdp makes "only" the connection available but does not provide the screen content. They are two separate programs. So you can install xrdp easily and also a VNC server `sudo apt-get install vnc-common vnc4server` to get sesman-Xvnc running. Or you install manually with this great tutorial the X11rdp server (then you also need to install the newest xrdp manually):

http://scarygliders.net/2011/11/17/x11rdp-ubuntu-11-10-gnome-3-xrdp-customization-new-hotness/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error in RHEL 6: [ERROR] another Xserver is already active on display... .

I was able to get xrdp to work by installing gnome packages. I do not have my initial list of gnome packages. The package names may be different on other Linux distributions. Adding these got xrdp working:

Added packages:

```
gnome-desktop
gnome-session-xsession
gnome-applets
gnome-menus
```

(NOTE - many other packages were installed as dependencies. It is very possible that it was installation of one of the dependencies actually fixed this problem.)

Final list of gnome packages I have installed are:

```
gnome-applets
gnome-desktop
gnome-doc-utils-stylesheets
gnome-icon-theme
gnome-keyring
gnome-menus.
gnome-panel
gnome-panel-libs
gnome-python2
gnome-python2-applet
gnome-python2-bonobo
gnome-python2-canvas
gnome-python2-desktop
gnome-python2-extras
gnome-python2-gnome
gnome-python2-gnomevfs
gnome-python2-libegg
gnome-session
gnome-session-xsession
gnome-settings-daemon
gnome-terminal
gnome-themes
gnome-user-docs
gnome-vfs2
```

I could not find any relationship of the xrdp error message to this fix. I made a guess that the error message may actually be a misrepresentation of the real error. This is why I tried installing additional gnome packages. Hope this helps someone else get by this problem.